# pass c++ function that contains struct to C# and convert it to c# function with Marshal.PtrToStructure

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, extern

I am very new to c++ so I might have some mistakes on this side.
So I started with writing simple C++ function that will contain struct as return type:

my c++ struct:

```
struct a {
   int i;
};
```

my c++ function declaration in library.h file:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) struct a retNumber();
```

my c++ function description in library.cpp file:

```
struct a retNumber()
{
   struct a r = a();
   r.i = 22;
   return r;
}
```

So I just want to compile it and then use it in c# code, I am getting following compile errors:

```
error C2371: 'retNumber' : redefinition; different basic types
error C2526: 'retNumber' : C linkage function cannot return C++ class 
error C2556: 'a retNumber(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void retNumber(void)'
```

That's the first part of my question and if you guys will help me to solve it, I will really appreciate it, once it's solved, I am going to declare the same struct in my c# code:

```
struct a1
{
    int i;
}
```

Then I am going to import my c++ function:

```
[DllImport("library.dll")]
public static extern a1 retNumber();
```

Once it's done, I will create GCHandle:

```
a1 test = retNumber();
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(test, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

and then I will try to convert my actual result and release memory:

```
        Object temp = Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(a1));
        handle.Free();
```

So by this time I should have object that is of type a1 and contains variable i with value 22.

If anyone can please delagate through this process I will greatly appreciate it!
Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: I really suggest that if you have 2 questions you ask them both separately.

Comment: they are dependable on each other, and c++ people will be able to see of what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the C++ side, you need to wrap everything in `extern "C"`, including the struct:

```
extern "C" {
    struct a {
       int i;
    };
};
```

On the C# side, you'll need to specify the calling convention properly:

```
[DllImport("library.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
public static extern a1 retNumber();
```

Once you do that, there is no need for the `Marshal.PtrToStructure` call.  Just do:

```
a1 test = retNumber();
Console.WriteLine(a1.i); // Should print 22
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Reed, if you can briefly explain in which cases I need to use  Marshal.PtrToStructure would be great, thanks

Comment: Alright, so I wrapped the struct, however compiler still complains about my function: struct a retNumber()
{
   struct a r = a();
   r.i = 22;
   return r;
}

Comment: @Stanislav Try using a typedef for hte struct declaration.